# Pyserial string to byte encoding to write to microcontroller

Tags: python, pyserial, serial-communication

I'm trying to communicate between my PC and a microcontroller (MC). My microcontroller will read using `getchar()` until 4 characters have been read or it bumps into the characters `'\0'`, `'\'`, or `'\r'`.

The communication works perfectly fine with hyper-terminal. However, my python script doesn't seem to be sending `'\0'`, `'\'`, or `'\r'` when encoding an input string and concatenating with one those special characters to it.

```
command  = input("Enter Command: ")
port.write(bytes(command + '\n', 'UTF-8'))
```

So if I entered the command `x` it should send `'x'`and`'\n'` and the MC should stop waiting for more characters to read because of the new line. However, if I enter only `x`, the MC will wait for 4 more characters to read.
How do I convert my string with the special characters properly to bytes? Thanks.

The MC code is:

```
buffer[ii] = getchar();

while(buffer[ii] != '\0' && buffer[ii] != '\n' && buffer[ii] != '\r' && ii < 4 - 1)
{
    buffer[++ii] = getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a string into an array of integers 0 <= N <= 256 by either:

`map(ord,command+'\n')`
or
`bytearray(command+'\n',"UTF-8")`

If you had to write each byte one by one to the port:

```
>>> for b in bytearray("message\n","UTF-8"):
...     port.write(b)
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. So I had to send one byte at a time, but add a 10 ms delay as well. Seems like python will send the entire message at a time while hyperterminal sends one byte at a time. getchar() seemed to look at the first char and then the rest of the data was lost with pyserial.  

One small changes to the for loop code above is b must be converted to a byte first.